# Add an event function using linq

Tags: c#, linq, event-handling

I have a collection of classes and I would like to add to the collection property change event function.

When I try to do this using LINQ with this code:

```
(from s in StreetsVI select s.PropertyChanged += 
    new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Messege)).ToList();
```

I get the error:

```
The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LINQ is aimed at *queries*. When you want to do something *to* each object, that's not a query - that's all about side-effects, and you should just use a normal `foreach` loop. LINQ is *not* designed for imposing side-effects on collections - and indeed side-effects don't play well with the lazy evaluation favoured by LINQ.

You should just use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var s in StreetsVI)
{
    s.PropertyChanged += Messege;
}
```

I'd also recommend that you read Eric Lippert's [`foreach` vs `ForEach`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) blog post, which discusses the philosophical differences between statements and expressions.

Note that if you *really* wanted to you could still use LINQ, by using a lambda expression with a statement body and a return statement after the event subscription... but it would be a perversion of LINQ to such an extent that I don't even want to include it in the answer. Even using `List<T>.ForEach` would be an improvement over that.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
foreach(var s in StreetsVI) {
    s.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Messege);
}
```

Comment: But I thought the loop because I have more complex situations in my program, I prefer to work only with the advance linq allows easily do Monifoltziot of where, if possible to do a trick and cause select to return any value, and in Al way "to get on this ride to assign an event it will be the best solution

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since you're making it a list, you can use the native [`.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28VS.80%29.aspx) method:

```
StreetsVI.ToList()
    .ForEach(s => s.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Messege));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select` must return a value.  Assigning an event to an event handler is not returning a value.